# Leave free access to internal intermediary functions in Haskell library?

Tags: haskell, testing, architecture, cabal, cabal-install

I'm writing a numerical optimisation library in Haskell, with the aim of making functions like a gradient descent algorithm available for users of the library. In writing these relatively complex functions, I write intermediary functions, such as a function that performs just one step of gradient descent. Some of these intermediary functions perform tasks that no user of the library could ever have need for. Some are even quite cryptic, but make sense when used by a bigger function.

Is it common practice to leave these intermediary functions available to library users? I have considered moving these to an "Internal" library, but moving small functions into a whole different library from the main functions using them seems like a bad idea for code legibility. I'd also quite like to test these smaller functions as well as the main functions for debugging purposes down the line - and ideally would like to test both in the same place, so that complicates things even more.

I'm unsurprisingly using Cabal for the library so answers in that context as well would  be helpful if that's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely not just throw such internal functions in the export of your package's trunk module, together with the high-level ones. It makes the interface/haddocks hard to understand, and also poses problems if users come to depend on low-level details that may easily change in future releases.

So I would keep these functions in an “internal” module, which the “public” module imports but only re-exports those that are indended to be used:

- Public

  ```
  module Numeric.Hegash.Optimization (optimize) where
  import Numeric.Hegash.Optimization.Internal
  ```
- Private

  ```
  module Numeric.Hegash.Optimization.Internal where

  gradientDesc :: ...
  gradientDesc = ...

  optimize :: ...
  optimize = ... gradientDesc ...
  ```

A more debatable matter is whether you should still allow users to load the `Internal` module, i.e. whether you should put it in the `exposed-modules` or `other-modules` section of your `.cabal` file. IMO it's best to err on the “exposed” side, because there could always be valid use cases that you didn't foresee. It also makes testing easier. Just ensure you clearly document that the module is unstable. Only functions that are so deeply in the implementation details that they are basically impossible to use outside of the module should not be exposed at all.

Comment: This is just the sort of insight I was looking for, thank you. Would you recommend putting all of the internal bits and bobs in one internal module, or should each separate module have its equivalent internal module - e.g. `gradient descent` & `gradient descent internal`, `newton optimise` & `newton optimise internal` etc?

Comment: That depends a lot on how big the project is, what kind of dependencies you have between the functions, etc.. I tend to consider splitting a module if it grows beyond 500 LOC, but I also have some modules with more than 1500 lines because of mutual dependencies that would be very awkward across multiple modules. Vice versa it sometimes makes sense to put some auxiliary stuff in an entirely new _package_, even if it's just two modules and less than 100 lines.

Comment: +1 to err on the "exposed" side by using importable `Internal` modules.  A library with exposed internals is typically much more useful than a library with hidden internals, and the primary use case of hidden internals seems to be some kind of library author fantasy that they'll someday find the time and inclination to rewrite the implementation from scratch in a manner that doesn't introduce any significant changes to the public interface.  I'll believe it when I see it.   See `lens` and `conduit` for examples of quality packages that properly expose their full internals.

Comment: Oh, and exposing data types with their constructors is typically the most useful aspect of exposing internals.  People can always write and/or copy their own intermediary / low-level functions, but only if they can access the internal data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively export functions from a module by listing them in the header. For example, if you have functions `gradient` and `gradient1` and only want to export the former, you can write:

```
module Gradient (gradient) where
```

You can also incorporate the intermediary functions into their parent functions using `where` to limit the scope to just the parent function. This will also prevent the inner function from being exported:

```
gradient ... =
  ...
  where
    gradient1 ... = ...
```

Comment: This answer appears to be about how to tell the compiler what to do, whereas the question as I read it is about how to choose the "what to do" part in the first place.

Comment: Whilst both of these are easy fixes, how do I then go about testing the intermediary functions? In some cases there are quite a few of them, and should changes need to be made down the line I feel it would greatly help debugging to have everything tested.

Comment: @DanielWagner indeed, the question as I meant it is mainly about what the common practice is here, thanks.